# tire burst AFTER overloading

Tags: tires

A colleague of mine overloaded his SUV by about 25-35% on one occasion. After some months passed one tire bursted on a highway at about 50-60mph. Could the overloading be one reason for the bursting tire or is this unlikely and the tire would have bursted instantly if it was due to the overloading?

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics.SE ... Really, there is no way to know. It might have been a contributing factor. A burst tire can be caused by many different factors. One of the big ones is underinflation. This causes a LOT of heat in the tire, which weakens the structure of the tire. I'm not sure if your question can be objectively answered.

Comment: is that 25% over the SUV rating or 25% over the tire max load. How was it inflated (You would typically run higher pressure for higher load, not over the tire max pressure of course ). How fast and how far was it run overloaded?

Answer (score 3):

It is generally impossible to say for sure whether the overloading caused the delayed tire failure or whether it would have caused the tire to fail right away (but did not, this time).

Most automotive components are rated below their failure points for two main reasons:

1. In the real world, there are a lot of variables and it is impossible to account for every combination. For example, a tire might be able to support different loads safely based on temperature, and temperature changes not only with ambient air temperature but also rotational velocity (speed: your tire's "speed" rating is actually a "heat" rating because the tire heats up as it spins faster and continuously deforms where it meets the road).

   It is safer simply to increase the safety margin than to give more complex guidelines that people might not understand. This means that overloading tires by a small margin *might* not be a big deal. Or it might be.
2. No matter what recommended limits engineers slap on a component such as a tire, someone is going to ignore that limit, add more weight, more speed, more something. Ideally the vehicle will not fail as soon as it runs up against whatever the limit is, as that will cause legal and financial headaches for the manufacturer (it costs money to defend against lawsuits, or fight public perception of low-quality manufacturing).

That being said, it is possible that a tire might degrade faster if continuously loaded right at its rated weight limit or is overloaded for a short time. The tire might not fail right away, either.

Imagine loading your car such that the tires are pushed *almost* to their breaking limit. You are driving along the road, and coming to the bottom of a hill - inertia is pushing your car down as you round the bottom of the hill and start ascending, increasing the effective load on the tires even more. Later in your trip you drive over train tracks, adding a lot of sudden bumps which both increase and decrease the tire load very quickly. Finally, you take a turn a little too quickly, increasing stress on the sidewalls.

You made your hypothetical trip with the tires intact, except for the microscopic tears in the sidewalls, the metal strips in the tire were deformed more than usual and cut into the inside of the tread slightly, and generally the tires have imperceptible defects that weakened their structure and may result in premature failure.

Or none of that happened and a subsequent failure is completely unrelated. We cannot know for sure.

---

If this were my vehicle, I would replace all four tires and perform usual due diligence on them - do not overload them, keep them properly inflated, rotate them regularly, balance and alignment check with every rotation, replace no later than 4/32" of tread remaining. Tires are extraordinarily important to the safe operation of a vehicle, and it is crucial to take care of them so they can take care of you.

I had a tire blow out on the highway at 80 MPH. Luckily it was a back tire and I could maintain control of the car. I have also hydroplaned on the highway with disastrous results. Now I respect my tires a whole lot more and have not had any problems since.